# Custom Django ForeignKey field to a defined model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.11 I'd like to make a custom model field that inherits from ForeignKey.

With a normal ForeignKey, you can do something like the following:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Instead, I'd like to make a model field that is largely the same as the ForeignKey field, but 1) uses a different default widget for the formfield and 2) doesn't require the model name to be placed as a positional parameter.

```
# myapp/models.py
from otherapp.fields import ManufacturerField

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerField()
```

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time overriding the **init** method of the child class to get my "Company" model inserted into the mix. Here's what I have so far by way of a modelfield (not working on the widget at all yet):

```
# otherapp/fields.py
from otherapp.models import Company

class ManufacturerField(models.ForeignKey):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ContentField, self).__init__(Company, **kwargs)
```

When I try to do this, I get:

```
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field manufacturer on myapp.Car: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'to'
```

Is there a property I can set on the custom modelfield class to specify that I want this to be a foreignkey to one specific model? If not, any ideas on how I can properly intercept the **init** method to feed in my model?

Answer (score 0):

`super()` referring to the base class explicitly. you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/6396981) to understand it.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ContentField, self).__init__(Company, **kwargs)
```

should be;

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ManufacturerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor/blob/master/martor/fields.py) how to custom the field.